# Error uploading artifacts to Nexus 3.6

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I inherited a Jenkins job that uploads artifacts to the artifact server.  I 
had to move to a new artifact server box so I installed the latest version 
of Nexus - 3.6.0-02.  I pointed the old Jenkins job to a new artifact server 
by updating the gradle.properties file (mavenServer and mavenReleases 
properties have changed).  Build.gradle file has uploadArchives task.  All 
servers are CentOS 7 boxes.

```
When the job runs, I get the following error:    

16:27:03.623 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Adding reference: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer
16:27:03.670 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Maven Ant Tasks version: 2.1.3
16:27:03.675 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Loading Maven settings file: /tmp/gradle_empty_settings2523667867595338296.xml
16:27:03.837 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] Deploying to http://myrepository.com:8081/repository/releases/
16:27:05.269 [ERROR] [system.err] Uploading: com/myfiles/6.0/myfile.jar to repository remote at http://myrepository.com:8081/repository/releases/
16:27:05.292 [ERROR] [system.err] Transferring 82562K from remote
16:27:06.832 [DEBUG] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7e351d76 pairs: {PUT /repository/releases/com/myfiles/6.0/myfile.jar HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: maven-artifact/3.0.4 (Java 1.8.0_51; Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64)}{Host: myrepository.com:8081}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 84543762}
16:27:06.838 [DEBUG] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7e351d76 pairs: {PUT /repository/releases com/myfiles/6.0/myfile.jar HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: maven-artifact/3.0.4 (Java 1.8.0_51; Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64)}{Host: myrepository.com:8081}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 84543762}
16:27:06.843 [ERROR] [system.err] Error writing to server
16:27:06.848 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Error deploying artifact 'com.myfiles:myfile:jar': Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
Error writing to server

16:27:06.852 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':uploadArchives'
16:27:06.853 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :uploadArchives FAILED
16:27:06.855 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :uploadArchives (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 3.702 secs.
16:27:06.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 3.869 secs, idle: 0.012 secs
16:27:06.870 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:27:06.872 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:27:06.873 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:27:06.874 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:27:06.876 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
16:27:06.878 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
16:27:06.879 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Error deploying artifact 'com.myfiles:myfile:jar': Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
16:27:06.880 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:27:06.881 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
16:27:06.884 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
16:27:06.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
16:27:06.885 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
16:27:06.886 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
16:27:06.886 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
16:27:06.887 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
16:27:06.888 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
16:27:06.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
16:27:06.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
16:27:06.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
16:27:06.891 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
16:27:06.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
16:27:06.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
16:27:06.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
16:27:06.893 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
16:27:06.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
16:27:06.894 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
16:27:06.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
16:27:06.895 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
16:27:06.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
16:27:06.896 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
16:27:06.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
16:27:06.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
16:27:06.897 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
16:27:06.898 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
16:27:06.898 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
16:27:06.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
16:27:06.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
16:27:06.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
16:27:06.900 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
16:27:06.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
16:27:06.901 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
16:27:06.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
16:27:06.902 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
16:27:06.905 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
16:27:06.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
16:27:06.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
16:27:06.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
16:27:06.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
16:27:06.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
16:27:06.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
16:27:06.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
16:27:06.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
16:27:06.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
16:27:06.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
16:27:06.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
16:27:06.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
16:27:06.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
16:27:06.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
16:27:06.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
16:27:06.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
16:27:06.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
16:27:06.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
16:27:06.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
16:27:06.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
16:27:06.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
16:27:06.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 44 more
16:27:06.918 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: Error deploying artifact 'com.myfiles:myfile:jar': Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
16:27:06.918 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DeployTask.doExecute(DeployTask.java:144)
16:27:06.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.CustomDeployTask.doExecute(CustomDeployTask.java:39)
16:27:06.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
16:27:06.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.execute(AbstractMavenResolver.java:111)
16:27:06.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:102)
16:27:06.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:80)
16:27:06.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:46)
16:27:06.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:79)
16:27:06.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
16:27:06.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
16:27:06.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
16:27:06.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
16:27:06.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:54)
16:27:06.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:64)
16:27:06.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 52 more
16:27:06.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
16:27:06.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:121)
16:27:06.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DeployTask.doExecute(DeployTask.java:125)
16:27:06.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 65 more
16:27:06.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file
16:27:06.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.finishPutTransfer(LightweightHttpWagon.java:213)
16:27:06.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:413)
16:27:06.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:392)
16:27:06.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:365)
16:27:06.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:163)
16:27:06.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:317)
16:27:06.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:227)
16:27:06.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:107)
16:27:06.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 66 more
16:27:06.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
16:27:06.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.finishPutTransfer(LightweightHttpWagon.java:185)
16:27:06.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 73 more
16:27:06.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:27:06.934 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
16:27:06.934 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
16:27:06.935 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
16:27:06.935 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 8.74 secs
16:27:06.937 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
16:27:06.937 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
16:27:06.940 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for build file '/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/build.gradle' (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/caches/2.3/scripts/build_2kdsl5mebg0wnqmevtb6j1bcf/ProjectScript/buildscript).
16:27:06.943 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on no_buildscript class cache for build file '/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/build.gradle' (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/caches/2.3/scripts/build_2kdsl5mebg0wnqmevtb6j1bcf/ProjectScript/no_buildscript).
16:27:06.946 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/caches/2.3/plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
16:27:06.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache artifact cache (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/caches/modules-2) was closed 0 times.
16:27:06.949 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache outputFileStates.bin (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/.gradle/2.3/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin)
16:27:06.951 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/.gradle/2.3/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin)
16:27:06.954 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/.gradle/2.3/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin)
16:27:06.956 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/.gradle/2.3/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin)
16:27:06.959 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/opt/jenkins/workspace/myfiles/.gradle/2.3/taskArtifacts).
16:27:06.961 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 0, cache instances: 0, modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
16:27:06.964 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 0 resolution results binary files in 0.0 secs
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

What could be the reason for this error?  I'm completely new to maven/nexus.

Thank you.

Comment: was there a change from http to https?

Comment: No, both repositories are http while jenkins is on https...

Comment: You should change your Jenkins job to run gradle with --debug flag, that should give you enough info so as to what went wrong.

Comment: I am running it with the debug flag.  It gives me "error writing to server" not much more there.  I put most of the error in the original post.

Comment: Can you put the full error in?

Comment: I updated the original question with the full error.

Comment: Any other suggestions?  Did the full error give a better picture?

Comment: Small files go through.  It's something related to larger files...

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that credentials are the same ? 
Did you verify that you can upload manually from Jenkins to the new Nexus server ?

Comment: I can SCP files easily.  Or did you mean uploading artifacts using curl?

Comment: Just make sure you can upload artifact , so no firewall or credentials blocks you

Comment: Yes, i can upload via curl: curl -v -u user:password --upload-file myfile.pom http://artifactserver:8081/repository/releases/myfiles/myfile.pom

Comment: Well the upload happens from the release step.  The release step just calls gradle upload  task.  Our build.gradle has uploadArchives task.

Comment: If I use the curl command in the Bash step - it does work.  So it's something related to gradle...  But the same gradle script worked just fine for the old repository.

Comment: Did you try Gradle locally ?

Comment: Yes, i tried running gradle via the command line on the server where jenkins executes the job (on a jenkins slave).  I still got an error.                                  Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file                                                                                                  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

Comment: Is it the same gradle version ? Did you check the gradle.properties ?

Comment: our gradle.properites doesn't have a gradle version.  Jenkins specifies version as Gradle2.3.  Nothing changed on the server where gradle runs.  I only updated gradle.properties with a new  mavenServer URL and mavenReleases have changed from /nexus/content/repositories/releases/  to  /repository/releases/

Comment: OK, i think i know where the problem is.  I can upload small files just fine.  It's the big files that give me an error.  Is there a setting on Nexus server?

Comment: Don't have any idea , currently working with Artifactory